# Avoid adding duplicate sheets to Excel Work book

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have a collection words inside `SheetNames` and i'm trying to add new `Worksheet` for each word inside `SheetNames`, please find the code below.

Before adding the `Worksheet` i'm trying to validate whether the sheet is already existing in my workbook using `sheetExists function`, code provided below.

```
For Each SheetName In SheetNames

     If sheetExists(SheetName , newWB) = False Then
        newWB.Activate
        Set FilPage = Worksheets.Add
        FilPage.Activate
        SheetName = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(SheetName, ".", " "), "[", " "), "]", " "), "/", "_"), "\", " ")
        If Len(SheetName) <= 30 Then
            FilPage.Name = SheetName
        Else
            SheetName = Left(SheetName, 23) & "-trimed"
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
    End If
Next
```

The code valediction using `function sheetExists` is not working consistently.

```
Function sheetExists(sheetToFind ,wb As Excel.Workbook) As Boolean

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    sheetExists = False

    For I = 1 To WS_Count
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name = sheetToFind Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

i can see some of the worksheet added with names "Sheet99" or "Sheet12" etc. even though `SheetName` is passed into the function. sometimes if `sheetExists function returns True` still workbook is trying to add a `worksheet`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a parameter `wb As Excel.Workbook` to your `Function sheetExists`, great, use it! why use then the hazardous `ActiveWorkbook`, which has all chances to be some other WB than the one you want to examine?

Replace all occurrences of `ActiveWorkbook` with `wb`

```
Function sheetExists(sheetToFind ,wb As Excel.Workbook) As Boolean
    WS_Count = wb.Worksheets.Count  ' <-------------------------------------- wb
    sheetExists = False

    For I = 1 To WS_Count
        If wb.Worksheets(I).Name = sheetToFind Then    ' <------------------- wb
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Moreover, the other code needs some corrections in addition to dropping the `Activate` stuff

```
For Each SheetName In SheetNames
     If Not sheetExists(SheetName , newWB) Then
        Set FilPage = newWB.Worksheets.Add
        SheetName = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(SheetName, ".", " "), "[", " "), "]", " "), "/", "_"), "\", " ")
        If Len(SheetName) > 30 Then SheetName = Left(SheetName, 23) & "-trimed"
        FilPage.Name = SheetName
        FilPage.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    End If
Next
```

---

The function SheetExists can be further simplified as: (Copyright @DavidZemens)

```
Function sheetExists(sheetToFind,wb As Excel.Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    sheetExists = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(sheetToFind)
    sheetExists = Not (ws Is Nothing)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, code looks clean now. 
How can i make this `Function sheetExists` function case sensitive?
For Example: If my excel have a sheet called `sheet1` and i pass `SHEET1` into `sheetToFind`, it should treat `SHEET1` as a new sheet.

Comment: @Ashwin You can't do that; sheet names ARE case insensitive! You wont be able to add a new sheet with an existing name with changing case.